# How to change git remote origin git:// to https://?

Tags: git, github

I wrote in git Bash this

```
git remote -v 
origin  git://github.com/devRena/test (fetch) 
origin  git://github.com/devRena/test (push)
```

and when i say

```
git push origin master 
fatal remote error: 
You can't push to git://github.com/devRena/test.git   
Use https://github.com/devRena/test.git
```

How to change git://github.com/devRena/test.git  to  https://github.com/devRena/test.git  ??

Comment: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/devRena/test.git`. To change the push url only, add the option `--push`. BTW, `git push https://github.com/devRena/test.git master` also works for one time.

Comment: I did it but not changed and i have the same error

Comment: git push https://github.com/devRena/test.git master
fatal: remote error:
  You can't push to git://github.com/devRena/test.git
  Use https://github.com/devRena/test.git

Comment: Run `git config -l` to see if there is `url.xxx.pushinsteadof` or `url.xxx.insteadof`.

Comment: there are url.https://.insteadof=git://   ,url.git://.insteadof=https:// , url.https://github.com/.insteadof=git@github.com

Comment: so it's caused by `url.git://.insteadof=https://`. Disable it from gitconfig by removing or commenting.

Comment: If you want to use SSH instead of HTTPS, you need to upload SSH key first. There's a documentation here: [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Answer (score 21):

Check the [Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) docs from GitHub:

Change your remote's URL with the `git remote set-url` command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

In your case, try this:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/devRena/test.git
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply edit by hand the .git/config file.

Find the section that starts with:

```
[remote "origin"]
```

Replace:

```
url = https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

with

```
url https://github.com/devRena/test.git
```

save